# Navigation graph not appearing in Android Studio 3.5

Tags: android-studio, android-navigation-graph

With Android Studio 3.5, I'm trying to create a navigation graph, but the design view is empty

[image]

I know this was an issue with 3.2 but its just not working in 3.5.

In my project build.gradle file I'm using

```
navigationVersion = '2.1.0'
```

In my app build.gradle file, I have it listed as

```
 // Navigation Components
 implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$rootProject.navigationVersion"
 implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$rootProject.navigationVersion"
```

Update:

- Re-installed Android Studio on my Mac after deleting all the cache , library files etc ... Still no luck.
- Tried to create another new project and I see the design view displaying the fragments.
- Any tips on where to compare the differences between both projects ?

Comment: go through this tutorial can helfull https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started

Comment: I do have the environment setup as mentioned in the tutorial. Any other tips ?

Answer (score 2):

This project was migrated from before I moved everything to AndroidX. After removing the following line from the gradle file ... the design view appeared.

```
androidTestImplementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-testing:$rootProject.navigationTestVersion"
```

Looks like Android Studio gets confused when it sees the older navigation dependency in the gradle file.